# How to set auto increment by 1 on a table in your migration script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How to set auto increment by 1 on a table in your migration script

> > `ALTER TABLE Table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

Is it possible to mention this during table creation or after that, in your DB migration scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are better solutions. Otherwise you can run raw SQL statements in migration scripts like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE Table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
```